# How to add an inner wrapper to an element in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want an angular diretive to add an inner wrapper to a DOM element. Unfortunately it's not wrapping but replacing the inner part of the element. ([see plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dCWolg3OeFjg6MOvcJW8))

So I have this html snippet:

```
<body ng-app="plunker">
  <div class="outer" wrapp-my-content>
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    <p>Hello {{name}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

The directive should change this into

```
<body ng-app="plunker">
  <div class="outer" wrapp-my-content>
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
        <p>Hello {{name}}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

But what I get is

```
<body ng-app="plunker">
  <div class="outer" wrapp-my-content>
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Directive Code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('wrappMyContent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var innerWrapper = angular.element('<div class="inner-wrapper" ng-transclude></div>');
      element.prepend(innerWrapper);
    }
  }
});
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed up `ng-transclude` and custom transclude by link:

**1. Use `template` of directive** ([demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/8AfSxI?p=preview)):

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

//Recommended angular-way
app.directive('wrappMyContent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    template:'<div class="inner-wrapper" ng-transclude></div>',
    link: function(scope, element) {
    }
  }
});
```

**2. Do transclude by custom link** ([demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/k7hrdc?p=preview)) :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

//Equals transclude by your self
app.directive('wrappMyContent', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:true,
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var innerContent = element.html();
      var innerWrapper = angular.element('<div class="inner-wrapper"></div>').append(innerContent);

      //Do compile work here.
      $compile(innerWrapper)(scope.$parent)
      element.empty().append(innerWrapper);

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: 1. merges the two divs into one `<div class="outer inner-wrapper" ng-transclude wrapp-my-content>`. What I need is nested divs.

Comment: 2. this works html wise. But the reinserted `innerContent` is not regocnised by angular. `ng-model` and `{{}}` are not compiled anymore.

Comment: Updated the code, add `$compile` for `innerContent`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a template for your `'<div class="inner-wrapper" ng-transclude>'` part instead of just making an element and prepending it... the ng-transclude directive won't be processed unless it's compiled which the template will be.